# C#, Get latest selected value from one of two ListBoxes

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem

Hi
I have six ListBoxes with names from different sources. Now I would like to get the name of the selected item in the most recently selected ListBox. How do I do that? I can't simply use ListBox.SelectedItem because I don't know what ListBox I want to get my information from.

Comment: Can you clearly explain what you need this was not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are responding to the event.  If so, the sender object should be the listbox that fired the event.

```
ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
var item = lb.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Each ListBox will have its own SelectedIndexChanged event, from there you'll know which ListBox it was which fired the event and then be able to use your SelectedItem property

Comment: if you're using the same events for multiple listboxes, John Kraft's answer covers you perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `autopostback="true"` set on each ListBox then the page will postback as soon as a name is selected, and you can use the sender object in the event handler to find out which ListBox was used.

Comment: Only really relevant if this is an ASP.NET project though?

Comment: Yes, thought at the time of writing, the OP hasn't said whether it's ASP.NET or WinForms.